# Directories of searching from the code sources

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

Visual Studio 2012 Premium Enu Update 3.

I can point to the necessary lib files in my C++ project's properties, but I can do it in my code too (as an alternative):
`#pragma comment(lib, "acad.lib")`

Are there similar ways for specifying *.h, and *.lib files directory search paths, instead of putting this info in my project's properties?

The same question is interesting for GCC 4.8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Visual Studio feature is known as [auto-linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx). I don't think you can set linker search paths in the source code that way.

There is no equivalent for telling GCC to link to certain libraries (in part because that is done by the linker, not by GCC).

In general I think it's a bad idea to embed absolute paths into source code, because the paths might be different if compiling and linking on a different machine, or as a different user. Those sort of configurable options belong in project properties or makefiles.